# Where can i get nohup.out, if script starts at startup

Tags: bash, nohup

test.sh in /root/folder

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Hello" #Sample Code
```

Now in th same folder(/root/folder). I have created nohup_test.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
while true
do
    sh /root/folder/test.sh
    sleep 1
done
```

If ran the above file like this `nohup sh nohup_test.sh &`. It will run in background and creates `nohup.out` have the output of `test.sh` which we can `tail -f nohup.out`

Now I want the above script nohup_test.sh to run start startup(automatically run at startup of OS).

I have created another file `start.sh` in same directory (/root/folder/)

```
#!/bin/bash
nohup sh /root/folder/nohup_test.sh &
```

I followed one procedure [HERE](https://askubuntu.com/questions/228304/how-do-i-run-a-script-at-start-up).

```
  vi /etc/rc.local
```

Add the entry like below

```
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel
/root/folder/start.sh || exit 1   # Added by me
exit 0
```

I think script is starting(Checked with `ps aux | grep "nohup"`).But I didn't get the `nohup.out` file. So, how can I get that file `nohup.out` or I have to follow any procedure?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `cd /root/folder` at the top of `start.sh`.  Never trust the current directory in startup jobs.

BTW, this is overly complex. You do not need nohup for jobs that are not started by a terminal; so you can use in `/etc/rc.local`

```
/root/folder/nohup_test.sh > /root/folder/my_output_file.log 2>&1 &
```

and be done.

Comment: At the end, you mentioned `2>&1`, can you please explain that.

Comment: @Veerendra `2>&1` simply redirects `sdterr` to `stdout`, so that both output streams are saved in your `nohup.out` file. Otherwise it could probably create a `nohup.err` file for the other stream as well if needed.

Comment: Thanks @ByteCommander, How can I limit the log size in this scenario? Can you please tell. Thanks

Comment: @Veerendra I'm sorry, but I don't know. This is probably a bit complex. If you only want the size limited for viewing, you can use the `less` viewer for example, or the `tail` command.