# Howto autostart a java -jar file after MySQL (mariadb) has started in Xubuntu 16.04?

Tags: java, mysql, autostart, mariadb, jar

I used to run this script in Startup and Session in Xubuntu 14.04 to autostart my java app:

```
xfce4-terminal -e "bash -c \"cd /home/restaurant/Documents/dist/ && java -jar POSv2.jar; exec bash\""
```

but running the same script in 16.04 causes MySQL Exceptions; I assume these exceptions were thrown because MySql wasn't loaded yet when the script ran. Therefore my question to you how can I make sure the script only get called once MySQl has been loaded successfully?

Answer (score 0):

Create a script that start every boot that checking every 2 seconds if `MySql` process is running, if so execute your command.

Lets create the script called `filename.sh` with this content:

```
#!/bin/bash
APP="gedit"
while true; do    
    PID=`pidof $APP`
    if [ ! -z $PID ]; then
        # We found the process running on the system.            
        java -jar "/home/restaurant/Documents/dist/POSv2.jar"
        exit 0
    fi
    sleep 2
done
```

make it executable:

```
chmod +x filename.sh
```

Just change `APP="gedit"` to the process name instead of `gedit`.
Make it running at the start up: [How do I run a script at start up?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/228304/how-do-i-run-a-script-at-start-up).

Comment: Hi Benny, thanks a lot for your input. I will try to implement and test the solution you are proposing. I will give a feedback afterwards.