# startup .sh script not working

Tags: command-line, scripts, xfce, chromebook, crouton

ok so I recently installed Ubuntu on my Chromebook using xfce4 and crouton and in order to make natural scrolling and 3 finger tap work I have to run the commands

```
synclient vertscrolldelta=-73
synclient horizscrolldelta=-73
synclient clickfinger3=2
synclient tapbutton3=2
```

on startup. another page told me to put it in a .sh script, so I've done that, created a .touchpadnaturalscrollingfix.sh with those 4 lines preceded by a `#!/usr/bin/bash`

and I set it up to run the script on startup in the session and startup but it didn't actually do it when I started up and I had to run the commands manually to get them to work... so how do i get it to run the commands on startup?

Comment: Did you make the script executable? is `bash` really in `/usr/bin` (usually it's `#!/bin/bash` on Ubuntu systems)?

Comment: i don't know what you mean make the script executable or how to do that, but you are right about the location of bash, i will edit that

Comment: To make it executable: `chmod +x path/to/.touchpadnaturalscrollingfix.sh`

Comment: ok i figured it out! when adding it to the startup application i was just putting the path but i needed an sh command before the path. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You may look this previous post of the same problem like you. I thin it will help you and solve your problem.
[How do I run a script at start up?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/228304/how-do-i-run-a-script-at-start-up)