# How to remove all the files inside the directory at AWS instance launch?

Tags: aws

I want to remove all the files and folders inside the particular directory at /var/www/example directory using user data script at AWS instance launch. Can you please help me.

Comment: Maybe you just need run bash script at system startup like here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/228304/how-do-i-run-a-script-at-start-up ? You can change script to rm -rf /var/www/example/*

Answer (score 0):

From [Amazon's Cloud Service website](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html):

---

The following example shows how to specify a script using a text file. Be sure to use the file:// prefix to specify the file.

```
aws ec2 run-instances --image-id ami-abcd1234 --count 1 --instance-type m3.medium \
--key-name my-key-pair --subnet-id subnet-abcd1234 --security-group-ids sg-abcd1234 \
--user-data file://my_script.txt
```

The following is an example text file with a shell script.

```
#!/bin/bash
rm -rf /var/www/example
```