# How to run a linux shell command at startup in Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: 20.04

I came across several answers, which will not work. I mean this is not a hard requirement, right? It should be straightforward and answered straightforward.

Comment: there are many ways of doing so, as even stated by yourself - but we cannot really help you unless you provide us with any steps / manuals / answers on AU you've tried so far, and what exactly is your goal (i.e: create x / do y / print z).

Comment: Clarify which ones "will" not work. This isn't [Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) - it's perfectly OK to have multiple ways to do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the best way is to use cron.
On your terminal, run `crontab -e` and add the following line:

```
@reboot <your_command>
```

The `@reboot` jobs will run when the cron daemon starts.

For more details, check this [link](https://askubuntu.com/a/228333/822295)